# Fill WinForms DataGridView From Anonymous Linq Query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql, datagridview

// From my form

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

private void fillStudentGrid()
{
     bs.DataSource = Admin.GetStudents();
     dgViewStudents.DataSource = bs;
}
```

// From the Admin class

```
public static List<Student> GetStudents()

{
    DojoDBDataContext conn = new DojoDBDataContext();

    var query =
        (from s in conn.Students
         select new Student
         {
             ID = s.ID,
             FirstName = s.FirstName,
             LastName = s.LastName,
             Belt = s.Belt
         }).ToList();

    return query;
}
```

I'm trying to fill a datagridview control in Winforms, and I only want a few of the values. The code compiles, but throws a runtime error:

*Explicit construction of entity type 'DojoManagement.Student' in query is not allowed.*

Is there a way to get it working in this manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have an `IEnumerable<Student>` instance and you cannot project entities from a query for the reasons described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/1ce25da3-44c6-407d-8395-4c146930004b))

You also don't need to create a list to bind to this data source - you can greatly simplify your method by changing it to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
{
    return new DojoDBDataContext().Students;
}
```

There is no reason to project a new instance to only map a few of the properties, by executing the query you are returning all the values anyhow and your projection doesn't save you anything.  If you really want to only return a few values from this query for the purposes of information hiding you could do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Object> GetStudents()
{
    DojoDBDataContext conn = new DojoDBDataContext();

    return conn.Students
               .Select(s => new {
                   ID = s.ID,
                   FirstName = s.FirstName,
                   LastName = s.LastName,
                   Belt = s.Belt 
               });
}
```

**Edit:** If you aren't using C# 4 you will have to cast the contents of the `IEnumerable<T>` to `Object` explicitly.  Only C# 4 supports covariance for `IEnumerable<T>`.  So if you are using C# 3 you will have to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Object> GetStudents()
{
    DojoDBDataContext conn = new DojoDBDataContext();

    return conn.Students
               .Select(s => new {
                   ID = s.ID,
                   FirstName = s.FirstName,
                   LastName = s.LastName,
                   Belt = s.Belt 
               }).Cast<Object>();
}
```

Comment: I'm projecting a new Student instance because... well I don't really know what I'm doing (obviously). I can get the all the info from all the students easily, but I only NEED a few of the fields and am filling the datagrid view at runtime as it's read only.

Answer (score 4):

Once I was looking around for a solution to display results on a Gridview.
The problem I had was that I forgot to set property of datagrid : "Data Source" to None on Winform.

This is simple solution for display gridview with linq (just sample code)

```
DataGrid dataGrid1 = new DataGrid();

var custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    select cust;

dataGrid1.DataSource = custQuery;
```

Comment: Was looking at all the advanced binding-related solutions and overlooked the simplest. This one solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just return a list of objects of an anonymous type :

```
public static List<object> GetStudents()
{
    DojoDBDataContext conn = new DojoDBDataContext();

    var query =
        (from s in conn.Students
         select new
         {
             ID = s.ID,
             FirstName = s.FirstName,
             LastName = s.LastName,
             Belt = s.Belt
         }).Cast<object>().ToList();

    return query;
}
```

Comment: Great, that works! I can't help but to think there's a better way than casting though.

Comment: Well, you can't return a list of an anonymous type, an a `List<anonymous type>` can't be assigned to a list of objects... so you have to cast. Anyway, it would probably better to return real Student objects from GetStudents, and perform the projection only before you assign the datasource